# ¿Cómo respetar las líneas de espacio en una variable, con Django?

Tags: html, python, django

Esto es algo sencillo: saber cómo hacer que la variable respete las líneas de espacio de un `models.TextField()` en django.
La tabla es esta:

```py
class Trabajo(models.Model): contenido = models.TextField() ...
```

en el *HTML* luego muestro:

```
<p> {{trabajo.contenido}} </p>
```

Supongamos que cuando lo que tiene es:

> "hola,
>
> ¿como estas"

En el *HTML* me muestra

> "hola, ¿como estas?".

¿Saben si hay algún filtro de variable en django que me permita hacer que respete las líneas de espacio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, precisamente existe el filtro [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) para esto que quieres. Para que surta efecto, no utilices las tags `<p>` manualmente, ya que el filtro las añadirá por ti, según corresponda.

Es decir, solo coloca lo siguiente:

```
{{ trabajo.contenido|linebreaks }}
```

Comment: Una solución jinja. No lo pensé antes. La tuya es mucho mejor :)

Comment: La tuya también es buena, colega. Es bueno tener las dos alternativas @ArielMontes

Answer (score 2):

En html no se reconocen los saltos de linea, para eso está la etiqueta `<br>` y para separar un párrafo de otro esta la etiqueta `<p>`. de manera que el siguiente código

```
<p>Hola

Mundo</p>
```

Devuelve:

```
Hola Mundo
```

## Solución

En django:

```
contenido = "Hola <br> Mundo"
```

O de lo contrario:

```
contenido = "Hola \n Mundo"
contenido.replace('\n','<br>')
```

En HTML:

```
<p> {{trabajo.contenido}} </p>
```

Devolverá:

```
Hola
Mundo
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el formulario se le da a una persona no le puedo pedir que ponga un <br> en ves de linea de espacio, pero si se que existen porque en PHP me pasaba lo mismo y solo tenias que agregarle una funciona la variable para que deje las lineas de espacio.

Comment: Puedes usar `contenido.replace('\n', '<br>')` para sustituir los saltos de linea en el string por saltos de linea html

Comment: Ya me dijeron cual era el filtro de variable que buscaba, aun que tu repuesta es igual de valida porque también resuelve el problema. ¡gracias!

Comment: {{ trabajo.contenido|linebreaks }} si añades el |linebreaks en una variable hace que respete las lineas de espacio, pero tiene que estar fuera de un <p>